# How do I make the shape image come out of the corner?

Tags: excel, vba

The code reads the address on the right to display the shape image whenever you change it to each cell.
However, the image is cut off because of the poor location.
How do I fix the image of the shape on the upper right of the Excel?

Separately, when the code moves on to the next cell, the old image remains intact.
How can I erase the existing image when I move on to another cell?

[image]

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = Range("C:C").Column Then
    
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
          Filename:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value, _
          LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
          SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
          Left:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Left, _
          Top:=ActiveCell.Top, _
          Width:=400, Height:=400
        
        Exit Sub
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If the image shows up too far to the right, why don't you reduce the horizontal offset (the `Left` property)? Likewise, you can use `Offset` to adjust the vertical position, no?

Answer (score 2):

The following doesn't address the image position, but allows you to remove the previous image before adding the new one.

You could use a global variable to store a reference to the old image (instead of the extra sheet) but if VBA loses the reference or you save/reload excel the reference would be lost so  you would need more code to remove images before saving, and to check for lost images etc.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Image As Shape

Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hidden")

Set Image = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value)

If Target.Column = Range("C:C").Column Then

    If Not Image Is Nothing Then Image.Delete

    Set Image = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture( _
        Filename:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value, _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
        Left:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Left, _
        Top:=ActiveCell.Top, _
        Width:=400, Height:=400)
    
    Sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = Image.Name

    Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

If your worksheet doesn't have any other images/shapes, you could also do the following

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Image As Shape

If Target.Column = Range("C:C").Column Then

    ' delete all shapes
    For Each Image In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Image.Delete
    Next

    Set Image = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture( _
        Filename:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value, _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
        Left:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Left, _
        Top:=ActiveCell.Top, _
        Width:=400, Height:=400)

    Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```